# Enter to open a file or a folder in Macintosh Explorer

Tags: keybindings, macos

Is it possible to configure [Macintosh Explorer](http://www.ragesw.com/products/explorer.html) so that pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> opens a file or a folder (as [we can do in Finder](https://superuser.com/a/851632/116475))?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using Macintosh Explorer specifically? I see it has been discontinued.

Comment: @StuartH Yes, I am looking for a [File browser with treeview](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161867/20338). Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if it offers the functionality you're seeking, but possibly Path Finder? http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/

Comment: @StuartH Thanks, it doesn't have a treeview :(