# File browser with treeview

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, file

I am looking for a file browser for Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) with as many following features as possible (approximately ordered by descending importance):

- has a treeview along with the main pane
- automatically synchronize treeview with main pane
- editable address bar
- pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or mouse single left click on a folder/file opens it
- display file extension
- tabs
- can display a folder's content as a detailed list
- bookmark / favorite
- can display hidden files
- a decent search feature
- automatically expand tree node on selection
- still maintained

---

[Macintosh Explorer](http://www.ragesw.com/products/explorer.html) (free) is the best I have found so far: it fits all requirements except that it is no longer maintained, does not automatically expand tree node on selection, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or mouse single left click on a folder/file does not open it.

[image]

[MagicanFile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/magicanfile/id435051897?mt=12) (free) is another great option: it fits all requirements except that but it doesn't have tabs, It doesn't have bookmarks, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or mouse single left click on a folder/file does not open it, and the last update was Jun 29, 2011.

[image]

Is there any other great option? I am basically looking for an equivalent of  [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) (Windows).

[image]

Comment: By "pain" he means "pane".

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, Mac Dictation can be paneful to use!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QuollEyeTree has many of these features http://binnie.id.au/QuollEyeTree.html

It was designed as a XTree/ZTreeWin implementation for OSX.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it has any feature Macintosh Explorer does not, but at least it is still maintained!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I am biassed (being the author), but it does lots. It is principally designed to be used with the keyboard e.g. 'O' will Open a file (not "Enter" which has other functionality).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there were so [many keyboard shortcuts](http://binnie.id.au/Downloads/QuollEyeTree.pdf). That's very good to know as I use voice recognition for most tasks and could bind voice commands to some shortcuts.  By the way any idea regarding [Moving the treeview to the left side in QuollEyeTree](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/161925/20338)?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I explored lots of options early on, but was heavily influenced by ZTreeWin. "Enter" in file window will toggle this to use the full height (showing the max no of files), but I will look at the possibility.

Comment: I might have missed this, and the OP might not have asked for it, but I didn't find a "Duplicate folder" function, which would be really handy. A great program none-theless. Ditto Easy Explore, written up below.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin There is no need for "Duplicate folder". Just copy the Directory, renaming in the dialog box if required.

Answer (score 5):

just stumbled onto your question. I use "Easy Explore", it's on the Mac Store. It fits all your requirements -except the tab feature:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-explore/id789939414?mt=12

you could give it a go (even has picture preview functionality)

[image]

Comment: I might have missed this, and the OP might not have asked for it, but I didn't find a "Duplicate folder" function, which would be really handy. A great program nonetheless. Ditto QuollEye Tree, written up above.

Answer (score 3):

XnViewMP (of all platforms) may be what you want. Although I find it for a image viewer, it works fine as a file manager, resembling the classic Windows File Manager. Configure the layout as you wish.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a app called Omni Disk Sweep.

It is meant to delete files, but it has a nice file view.

[OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/more)

> OmniDiskSweeper is really great at what it does: showing you the files
>   on your drive, in descending order by size, and letting you decide
>   what to do with them. Delete away, but exercise caution. (Requires OS
>   X v10.8+)

And it looks like this:

[image: omni]

```
YES has a treeview along with the main pane
YES automatically synchronize treeview with main pane
NO editable address bar
YES pressing ENTER or mouse single left click on a folder/file opens it
YES display file extension
? tabs
YES can display a folder's content as a detailed list
NO bookmark / favorite
YES can display hidden files
NO a decent search feature
YES automatically expand tree node on selection
YES still maintained
YES shows all files (including system files)
```

One app to see fall files in organized manner in tree format (horizontal)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't have a treeview (like in the screenshots in put in the question) though: I don't want to have one column per tree level :( It also has almost no feature.

Comment: It is just the column view from finder but shows the size all directories and you cannot do anything but delete from it - so nothing like what the question asks for

Comment: @Mark thank you for your opinion! Your assessment is wrong. See the table showing it accomplishes over 80% of all requirements without a need to install another 3d party app.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I proposed it in the effort of trying to eliminate installing another 3d party app, since one newer knows what problems they might bring. I also updated my answer highlighting the features it has.

Comment: Given that description doesn't Finder in column mode do more?

Comment: @Mark, granted it is similar yet different view. My motivation is to avoid installing another 3d party apps, and the QuallEyeTree for example is to intrusive in to OS X operations for my taste.