# Moving the treeview to the left side in QuollEyeTree

Tags: file, macos

Is there any way to move the treeview to the left side in [QuollEyeTree](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161918/20338)? By default the treeview is located at the top half:

[image]

For example in [Macintosh Explorer](http://www.ragesw.com/products/explorer.html) the treeview is on the left side by default:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments got me thinking, and I knocked up a vertically oriented view.
This works, but hasn't been through a full testing cycle.

I will probably include this in the full version, with options for either mode. This will require another set of changes to allow independent configuration of both modes.

---

EDIT
I included the vertically oriented view as an option in the normal Beta
http://binnie.id.au/Downloads/QuollEyeTree-2.03.dmg